# How to make line graph be one continuous line

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to visualize my data however when I plot the points, the lines seem to go everywhere.

Here is the snippet of the data

```
Date    time_began  time_end    activecalls date_start  date_end
7/3/2020    14:08:47    14:09:30    2   7/3/2020 14:08  7/3/2020 14:09
7/3/2020    14:06:05    14:06:48    4   7/3/2020 14:06  7/3/2020 14:06
7/3/2020    15:11:36    15:12:19    6   7/3/2020 15:11  7/3/2020 15:12
7/3/2020    13:37:52    13:38:35    1   7/3/2020 13:37  7/3/2020 13:38
7/3/2020    14:19:31    14:20:14    3   7/3/2020 14:19  7/3/2020 14:20
7/3/2020    13:58:01    13:58:44    1   7/3/2020 13:58  7/3/2020 13:58
7/3/2020    16:56:32    16:57:15    3   7/3/2020 16:56  7/3/2020 16:57
7/3/2020    16:15:26    16:16:09    6   7/3/2020 16:15  7/3/2020 16:16
7/3/2020    14:35:16    14:35:59    3   7/3/2020 14:35  7/3/2020 14:35
7/3/2020    15:54:48    15:55:31    9   7/3/2020 15:54  7/3/2020 15:55
7/3/2020    16:01:39    16:02:22    3   7/3/2020 16:01  7/3/2020 16:02
7/3/2020    15:52:51    15:53:34    4   7/3/2020 15:52  7/3/2020 15:53
```

When I run it, the chart looks like this:
[image: What it looks like]

Here is what I want it to look like:
[image: What I want it to look like]

Comment: Please show data of "time_began" and "time_end"

Comment: Sorting the data by date before plotting should solve it

Comment: I have added the other data. I tried adding df.sort_values(by="date_start") right before the plotting and I don't think it made a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the code you've used to plot the data, it's the data itself that is not matching your expectation. I've made some assumptions here but based off previous work I think there's two things you want to do to correct this

#### Date Range in Data

You've overwritten you're dataframe to limit your data to only include information from `'7/1/2020 16:08'` to `'7/4/2020 15:10'` here:

```
mask = (df['date_start'] > day1) & (df['date_end'] <= day2)
df = df.loc[mask]
```

I'm not sure if this is intentional just to check the first few days but your expected chart goes up to 2009 so I'd recommend removing these lines.

#### Active Calls - Try using an aggregation for each day

Looking at the figures in your data snippet and comparing to your expected output the data is quite granular from 2002 - 2009. If you want to aggregate the **sum of active calls by day** you want to include a groupby() with a pd.Grouper() to specify the frequency of day:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_start', freq='D'))['activecalls'].sum()
```

From here you can simply plot the data adding .plot() which will by default plot a line chart as the index is now your date field (aggregated by day):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date_start', freq='D'))['activecalls'].sum().plot()
```

**Finally**, there's a few inconsistencies in your code it would be good to go through and clean these up:

1. You don't need to convert `date_start` and `date_end` into pd datetimes twice so you can remove the second instance of this.
2. You've overwritten the column `activecalls` with another method of creation. Determin which is correct and remove the other one.